# How do I make Observable await for async callbacks in next() and call them in order of subscription?

Tags: typescript, async-await, rxjs

It seems I should manage to find the answer just by googling around, but I could not, so here I am.

Let's say I have this code:

```
const something = async (): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, _reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 500);
    });
};

const s = new Subject<number>();
s.subscribe(async (n) => {
    await something(); 
    console.log(n);
});
s.subscribe(async (n) => {
    await something(); 
    console.log(n + 1);
});
s.next(1);
```

is that code guaranteed to always output

```
1
2
```

in that exact order? Well, it turns out it will probably output that, because both Promises have a 500ms delay, but there's no guarantee. In fact if I change the code to:

```
const something = async (): Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, _reject) => {
        const waitFor = Math.random() * 1000;
        setTimeout(() => resolve(waitFor), waitFor);
    });
};

const s = new Subject<number>();
s.subscribe(async (n) => {
    const delay = await something(); 
    console.log(n + " / " + delay);
});
s.subscribe(async (n) => {
    const delay = await something(); 
    console.log((n + 1) + " / " + delay);
});
s.next(1);
```

then you can experience the second subscriber sometimes running before the first finishes, based on the random delay each one gets.

Now I need the subscribers to run in the same order they subscribed, but I can't provide blocking callbacks, because my callbacks must be `async` in order to `await` for anything.

Is there a way to make Observable itself await for each subscriber before calling the next one?

Comment: *"Well, it turns out it will probably output that, because both Promises have a 500ms delay, but there's no guarantee."* There is if they have the same timeout like that. But I'm guessing your real situation is more like the version with random timeouts. No guarantee then. :-)

Comment: *"Now I need the subscribers to run in the same order they subscribed..."* It sounds like you want a **single** subscription that runs a series of callbacks in the order they register.

Comment: That would be completely against the purpose of an observable and the [pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) it's based on. All subscribers (which could be zero, one or many) are notified simultaneously (or as close to that as possible, it will strictly be sequential) then what they do with that is entirely up to them.

Comment: As the other comments point out, an Observable is probably not the right tool that you want.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual misconception here is, that you think observables will do something with a return value from a `subscribe` call, which is not the case.

As you can see in the function source code of observables (`subscribe(next: (value: T) => void): Subscription;`), this function should be a void function. Defining your function as `async` basically returns a promise, which is not used by the observable. Therefore the observable will also not wait for any subscription to finish.

It kind of seems like you are trying to misuse the intended information flow for observables (which is strictly from the observable to subscribers) in order to return some information back to the stream. You will not be able to achieve this.

I suggest you to describe the actual use case (like business logic) in a question. You will probably get a hint on which kind of `rxjs` operators to use in order to achieve the expected result.

Comment: Indeed, after reading your answer I've now realized I need the subscribers to share their results between each other. I'm afraid I have to scratch the `Subject` and use a plain old callback model.

Comment: I mean, it kind of seems like you try to switch from one observable to another (or a promise). This can be done with different rxjs operators, like `switchMap` or `mergeMap`. Maybe you can see if this fits your needs.